# Converting a single list input item into a string to concatenate with a file location

Tags: python, string, list, file

I am trying to record certain file information into a dictionary based on a user input list containing trial names.

```
def health(input):
    file_location = "./data/health_data/"
    dictionary= {}

    return(dictionary)
```

and I have a set of files in the health_data folder such as 010.csv 011.csv 012.csv etc.

A user can input a list of drug trials such that it would look like:

```
input = ["010", "011"]
```

So what I want to do is run a loop so that each list item is concatenated to the file_location so that it could look like:

```
for i in input:

    file_location ="./data/health_data/i.csv"
```

What I am struggling with is concatenating the input into the file location string. I have tried  `.join()` and have tried adding them but I get the error that only str can concatenate to str, not "list"

How can I convert the list given in input into a string that I can then concatenate it to the file_location variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 3.6+, you can use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
for i in input:
    file_location = f"./data/health_data/{i}.csv"
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: @McMckinson Since you're dealing with filesystem paths, you should consider using pathlib if things become any more complex.